# DataTable Always Returns 0

Tags: c#

My query returns results, but for some reason my DataTable always shows 0.  The only thing I altered was the fact that I added parameters to the C# syntax (altho if I manually run the stored procedure it returns results).  This is my syntax, does anyone see something that is incorrect syntactically in it?

```
protected void btnPress1464()
{
    RunSQLStoredProc();
    DataTable tableA = ebdb.Tables[0];
    if (this.dtgAttendanceTracker.Items.Count == 0)
    {
        this.gvwTest.DataSource = tableA
        this.gvwTest.DataBind();
    }
}

public DataSet RunSQLStoredProc()
{
    ebdb = new DataSet(); 
    SqlQueryBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    SqlQueryBuilder.Append("exec alphadawg ");
    ebdb = DoThis(SqlQueryBuilder.ToString());
    return ebdb;
}

public DataSet DoThis(string sqlQuery, int employeeid, DateTime hiredate, DateTime terminationdate)
{
    try
    {
        System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings connstring = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLServer1"];

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring.ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employeeid", employeeid.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hiredate", hiredate.ToShortDateString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@terminationdate", terminationdate.ToShortDateString());
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);                    
                adapter.Fill(ebdb);
                conn.Close();
            }                
        }
        return ebdb;
    }
    catch (Exception exception) { throw exception; }
}
```

Comment: What is `ebdb`? Why do you return the `DataSet` from a method when it's actually a field in your class that you return? Instead initialize and fill it in the method, that's much clearer and also prevents issues when you load an aleady filled dataset(data will be appended by default).

Comment: Also I can't see how this code could compile. The DoThis method requires parameters that you don't pass at all in the call from RunSqlStoredProc

Comment: Using `AddWithValue` and converting your dates to some strings will produce **very** strange results. In fact it will add `varchar` parameters to your command instead of `DateTime`. Is it intended? Have you tried to use sql profiler to see what command is *actually* being executed at server?

Comment: @AndyKorneyev - how can I use SQLProfiler when running the procedure from C#?

Comment: @FartStopper in the same manner you're usually using it. Just run it and see what queries are being sent and executed on target sql server. It doesn't matter if these queries are executed from C# application or from anywhere else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `CommandText` should only contain the stored-procedure name and not also `exec` if the command's `CommandType` is `StoredProcedure`. The `StringBuilder` is also redundant.

I also think that the way how you use `AddWithValue` with the wrong types could cause this issue(look at the last paragraph of my answer):

So not

```
SqlQueryBuilder = new StringBuilder();
SqlQueryBuilder.Append("exec alphadawg ");
ebdb = DoThis(SqlQueryBuilder.ToString());
```

but

```
ebdb = DoThis("alphadawg", otherParamaters...);
```

It's also bad practice to pass a sql-string to a method that executes it, that often introduces sql injection issues. You should not have a method `DoThis` but `GetAlphaDawg` which encapsulates the sql-query and only pass the parameter-values.

Apart from that, why do you return the `DataSet` from a method if it's actually a field in your class that you return? Instead initialize and fill it in the method, that's much clearer and also prevents issues when you load an already filled dataset(data will be appended by default).

This would be a possible implementation. Note that you shouldn't use `AddWithValue` and don't use `String` for `DateTime` but **always use the correct type**, all the more if you use `AddWithValue` which needs to infer the type from the value:

```
public DataSet GetAlphaDawg(int employeeid, DateTime hiredate, DateTime terminationdate)
{
    DataSet dsAlpha = new DataSet();
    try
    {
        System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings connstring = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLServer1"];

        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connstring.ConnectionString))
        {
            using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter("alphadawg", conn))
            {
                da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                var parameter = da.SelectCommand.Parameters;
                parameter.Add("@employeeid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = employeeid;
                parameter.Add("@hiredate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = hiredate;
                parameter.Add("@terminationdate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = terminationdate;
                da.Fill(dsAlpha); // Open/Close not needed with Fill
                return dsAlpha;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception) { throw; }
}
```

Since you use `ToShortDateString`, if you actually want to remove the time portion of your `DateTime` use `DateTime.Date`, for example:

```
parameter.Add("@hiredate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = hiredate.Date;
```